# How can I create a WPF Combobox with suboptions

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

Is it possible to have a combobox that when you click in one of its items it opens a submenu where the final options would appear?
When collapsed the combobox text should be the one of the suboption selected.

We use infragistics, so something from them would also help.

Comment: Sounds like a silly UX, this will certainly confuse your users as you're confusing us with such question :D Personally I'd use a `GroupStyle` to outline different groups of options : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle(v=vs.110).aspx and keep it as usual, show the selection in `ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.selectionboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can modify template for combobox.
Copy default comboboxtemplate, modify it as you want and assign in style.
To copy template use Blend: in control context menu select "edit template" - you will get copy of default template.